# imagemagick montage: label images with part of filename

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to montage multiple files with names like these:

```
1235_9123a46d52ecb2de.png
123_6a51ef8968c64b94.png
1269_a7059318d47dbc01.png
12_45fb8c628863d77a.png
1347_04355d15f39e1e06.png
1349_bcbad21a686712d1.png
1368_229b9d3f692fdd61.png
1369_f69c36e04ba37bcb.png
137_ec3571cde47f7b8a.png
...
```

I want to label each image with only part of filename before underscore `_`

If I use the following command
    `montage -label %t * show:`
then whole filename is displayed that is quite long. Is it possible to extract substring from filenames somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substring operation wouldn't be supported with `montage` utility, but for what your doing, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) would be ideal.

```bash
 #!/bin/bash
 SOURCES="1235_9123a46d52ecb2de.png 123_6a51ef8968c64b94.png 1269_a7059318d47dbc01.png"
 # or SOURCES=$(find . -name "*.png")
 # Iterate over known files
 for FILENAME in ${SOURCES[@]}
 do
    # Substring up to first "_" character
    LABEL=$(echo $FILENAME | cut -d "_" -f 1)
    # Set meta-data label
    mogrify -label $LABEL $FILENAME
 done
 montage -label %l $SOURCES show:
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately there can be duplicates after removing second part. If you are interested, there is a solution that works better in my case: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=28203#p124820 Though, it is also not in one line...

Comment: @StasS Looks like that solution would require identical script. Updated answer to use `mogrify` to set meta-data

Comment: Warning: the `mogrify` command reads, processes and overwrites image files, which may lose information (if original images contain specific metadata that ImageMagick does not care about). If you do not want that, operate on copies of your images.